# AddObject to NSMutableArray crashes with DynemicCastClassUnconditional(BAD EXC)

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

I have a swift class of NSObject Type

```
class DBObject_Swift : NSObject
{

    //Objects for Category table.
        var CId : Int! = Int();
        var strCType : NSString! = NSString()
    //Objects for Event table.
        var EId : Int! = Int()
        var ECId : Int! = Int()
        var strETitle : NSString! = NSString()
        var strEDateTime : NSString! = NSString()
        var strOccurrence : NSString! = NSString()

    //Objects for ToDoEvent table.
        var TDId : Int! = Int()
        var TDEId : Int! = Int()
        var TDCId : Int! = Int()
        var strTask : NSString! = NSString()
        var strDate : NSString! = NSString()
        var strTDOccurrence : NSString! = NSString()
        var isCompleted : Int! = Int()
}
```

and the object of the above class i want to add in nsmutableArray

```
    while rs.next()
    {
        println("\(i++)");
        var dbObj : DBObject_Swift = DBObject_Swift();
        dbObj.CId = Int(rs.intForColumn("CId"));
        dbObj.strCType = rs.stringForColumn("CType");

        arrCategoryDBObj.addObject(dbObj as DBObject_Swift);
    }
```

but at last object added in array it crash with EXC_BREAKPOINT and in console status bar said DynemicCastClassUnconditional crash type

so please help me if anyone faces this kind of prob.

Comment: did you solve this problem? I have the same issue

Comment: When you have got this error and what you want to do please explain then i'll help you because my question is too old so..